# FastPDFKit get document size

Tags: iphone, ios

I might be overlooking this, but how can one get the size of a PDF if you're using FastPDFKit?

I'm trying to create PNG's from a pdf, but without knowing the actual dimensions of the page it's rather hard to get it right.

EDIT:
I searching in the documentation before, but all I found was this method:
`- (void)getCropbox:(CGRect *)cropbox andRotation:(int *)rotation forPageNumber:(NSInteger)pageNumber withBuffer:(BOOL)withOrWithout`

But I have no idea how to use it, it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how familiar you are with PDF, but each page specifies a number of "boxes" that are various rectangles of interest (crop, media, etc)

Most apps using PDF elect to use the crop box which defines the region of the page that should be displayed. (See section 10.10.1 of the PDF 1.7 specification: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference_archive.html)

Also of note is that a page can specify a rotation angle of 0, 90, 180, or 270 which you need to apply to the crop box yourself. (see /Rotate in table TABLE 3.27 of the PDF 1.7 spec)

So using the above API you would call it like so:

[somePDFDoc getCropbox:&cropbox andRotation:&rotation forPageNumber:10 withBuffer:NO];

This would give you the cropbox rect and it's rotation.

NOTE: I have never used FastPDFKit

NOTE2: If the value of cropbox is CGRectZero, you want to use one of the other rects. Most viewers use the media box instead.